# # of open jobs vs returned results very off shall we say

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

Go here:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/101707/software-engineer-net-quicken-loans

States there is one job available as shown:

[image]

Clicking the one job returns a list of jobs:

[image]

Comment: Well, they expect that one candidate to wear a *lot* of hats.

Comment: BAHAHAHAHAHHA @Pekka that was awesome.

Comment: @JonH are you still seeing this behavior? I wasn't able to reproduce this.

Comment: @G-Wiz - Did you follow my steps that I listed above?  It still doesn't work for me.

Comment: @JonH, my bad, I forgot that there is some filtering in place here. Employers have the opportunity to target their jobs to specific countries/regions. Across the site, we respect that targeting by hiding jobs that are not targeted to the region the request is coming from. One of the few exceptions is on company pages, where we intentionally show all jobs related to a company. In the case above, the last job has the "Allows remote" setting specified, which broadens the targeting of that one job.

Answer (score 3):

Adding [Mike's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312725/of-open-jobs-vs-returned-results-very-off-shall-we-say#comment284892_312725) as an answer,

> Employers have the opportunity to target their jobs to specific
>   countries/regions. Across the site, we respect that targeting by
>   hiding jobs that are not targeted to the region the request is coming
>   from. One of the few exceptions is on company pages, where we
>   intentionally show all jobs related to a company. In the case above,
>   the last job has the "Allows remote" setting specified, which broadens
>   the targeting of that one job.