# Get your J O B before they run out

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Every company on jobs has only 1 job available.  I mean EVERY company.
Get your J O B before they run out:

[image]

Comment: @DavidFullerton - Now that I think about it you are right, on that one I was so concentrated on clicking it and the results, where as this one I just noticed as I kept getting different companies all stating 1 job.  Please close.

Comment: done, but keep 'em coming!

Comment: @DavidFullerton - When will I ever get my swag...I give and you guys don't http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310598/wheres-my-swag all these bug reports and nothing for poor old me...its Christmas time you know :-).

Comment: David doesn't handle swag, @JonH; David *is* swag. Send a note to team@stackoverflow.com & we'll check on the status of whatever.

Comment: LOL @ David is swag.  i was kidding about the swag - im not that desperate for a shirt.

Comment: @DavidFullerton I'd reopen this actually, I stand correct http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies go there and look at every company it is listing one job.

Comment: @JonH there's definitely some bug with the company job count. But I see companies with 2 / 6 / 9 jobs that look correct.

Comment: @DavidFullerton - It's fine but a lot are wrong, I could always work for zalando http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/zalando (28 open positions, holy cow).

Comment: @JonH The last event we had was bigger than anything we've ever done. And, well, I suck at Google products. The last of it is going to our warehouse tomorrow, now that I've fixed it - I will put something extra in there in acknowledgement of your Jobs testingness.

Comment: Also, I _think_ this is completed, though caches abound may flutter with wit from ages past.

Comment: @TimPost, This is still broken.  As an example go to the job search page and click on Quick Loans open jobs (it states there is 1, but when you click on it there are about 5!).

Answer (score 1):

I just hit this one:

[image: more than one]

Comment: Hmm, I am seeing strange results, related to this one: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312725/of-open-jobs-vs-returned-results-very-off-shall-we-say 3 companies I just tried all say 1 available.  Clicking them gives me much more opportunities.

Comment: go here: http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies and look at the job number on every company.

Comment: That is legit.  Somebody will be fixing that ASAP.

Comment: This is still broken.