# Company page open jobs doesn't match company featured ad

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

Not sure if this is related to this:

[Get your J O B before they run out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312735/get-your-j-o-b-before-they-run-out/312736#comment286268_312736)

However, that question is marked **status:completed**.

And no I am not advertising for Quicken Loans, they are simply my guinea pig company.  In any event the number of jobs in the featured section as such:

[image]

Does not match the number of open positions in the company page, as such:

[image]